# nested list splitbutton list

Tags: jquery-mobile, nested-lists, split-button

I am trying to achieve the following using jQ Mobile (1.2 Alpha1), but haven't been able to after a few hours of trial and error:

I have a nested list of categories (container of items) and items, which can contain sub items too.

So each list of item can have potentially 2 click actions a. view list detail b. view sub items (which is what the nested list is for). In order to achieve the 2 action effect, I am using split button whenever a list contains sub items.

Here is my challenge:

Nested list by default makes the primary click action "view sub list", while making the split button an anchor that inherits the "additional" anchor you define in the li. So in my case, the primary action for a list will be "view sub list" and the split button "view details". But I want to switch the actions between them, making the split button do "view sub list".

I am not sure how to achieve the effect. If anyone has any idea, please share with me.